# codeigniter - Uninitialized string offset: 0 and Illegal string offset

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I loop in a loop and there are errors.
I tried this before but now it doesn't work.

My errors are:

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0
>
> Filename: views/audit_trail_view.php
>
> Line Number: 36
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cemo-marikina\application\views\audit_trail_view.php
>   Line: 36 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cemo-marikina\application\controllers\Employee.php
>   Line: 2819 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cemo-marikina\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'user_id'
>
> Filename: views/audit_trail_view.php
>
> Line Number: 36
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cemo-marikina\application\views\audit_trail_view.php
>   Line: 36 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cemo-marikina\application\controllers\Employee.php
>   Line: 2819 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cemo-marikina\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Views: audit_trail_view.php

```
<?php 
    $first_name='';
    $last_name='';
    $middle_name='';
    $separator="";
    $user_id="";

    ?>
        <table border ="1" width="75%" >
            <tr>
                <td>User</td>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($view as $view){

        $audit_id= $view['audit_id'];
        $audit_user_id= $view['audit_user_id'];
        $audit_record= $view['audit_record'];
        $audit_new_record= $view['audit_new_record'];

        $audit_date= $view['audit_date'];
        $timestamp=strtotime($view['audit_date']);


        $year=date('Y', $timestamp);
        $month=date('M', $timestamp);
        $day=date('d', $timestamp);
        $hour=date('h', $timestamp);
        $minute=date('i', $timestamp);
        $ap=date('a', $timestamp);
        foreach($users as $users){
            $id =$users['user_id'];
            if($id==$audit_id){
                $first_name=$users['fname'];
                $last_name=$users['lname'];
                $middle_name=$users['mname'];
            }
            else{
                $first_name='';
                $last_name='';
                $middle_name='';
            }

        }
    ?>  


        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $last_name." ".$first_name.", ".$middle_name;?> </td>
            <td><?php echo$audit_record.$separator.$audit_new_record;?> </td>
            <td><?php echo$month." ".$day.", ".$year." ".$hour.":".$minute." ".$ap;?> </td>
        </tr>   

    <?php   
    }





?>
    </table>
```

Controller:Employee.php

```
public function audit_trail_view(){
    $data['view']=$this->emp_model->audit_trail_view();
    $data['users']=$this->emp_model->audit_trail_users();
    $this->load->view("audit_trail_view.php",$data);
}
```

Model: Emp_model.php

```
/* AUDIT TRAIL VIEW START*/
    function audit_trail_view(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('audit_table');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function audit_trail_users(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
/* AUDIT TRAIL VIEW END*/

/* AUDIT TRAIL START */
    function audit_trail(){
        $data=array(
            'audit_user_id'=>$this->input->post('audit_user_id'),
            'audit_record'=>$this->input->post('audit_record'),
            'audit_new_record'=>$this->input->post('audit_new_record'),
        );
        $this->db->insert('audit_table',$data);
    }
/* AUDIT TRAIL END */
```

Comment: $id =$users['user_id']; - @Abdulla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for each seems odd:

```
  foreach($users as $users){
        $id =$users['user_id'];
         ....
```

Shouldn't it be more like:

```
  foreach($users as $user){
        $id =$user['user_id'];
        .....
```

I'm sure iterating and assigning to the same variable name is probably resulting in an unexpected array.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this Uninitialized string offset notice becuase of your foreach value, you can not use same variable name for values otherwise it will ve treated as overwrite.

**Change these:**

```
foreach($view as $view_value){
     $audit_id = $view_value['audit_id'];
     .......
}

foreach($users as $user_value){ 
      $id = $user_value['user_id'];
      .....
}
```